# Bitwise or of 2 tensors torch

Tags: lua, torch

How do I perform bitwise and/or operations on two tensors in torch?

Lets us say I have two ByteTensors a and b, I want to compute logical and/or between them. Is it possible to do it using a function?

Comment: There are element-wise operations implemented in Torch, but not bite-wise ones. You could solve the problem using https://github.com/LuaDist/luabitop inside a function with a loop that goes through the Tensors making the operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bitwise and/or operation for tensors in Torch. However, if you could convert each bit as a separate Tensor dimension (e.g. on your data preparation step, or with bitop), you can use [Torch.any(x)](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#torchanya) as element wise or  operation.

**Update:** it makes more sense to use torch.cmul and torch.add as mattdns [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38805698/213123)

```
a = torch.Tensor{0,1,1,0}
b = torch.Tensor{0,1,0,1}

th> torch.cmul(a,b):eq(1)
 0
 1
 0
 0
[torch.ByteTensor of size 4]

th> torch.add(a,b):ge(1)
 0
 1
 1
 1
[torch.ByteTensor of size 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what your looking for but might help.

```
x = torch.ByteTensor{1,1,0,0,0,0,1}
y = torch.ByteTensor{0,1,0,1,0,1,1}
```

And

```
z = torch.cmul(x,y) -- This gives and
th> z
 0
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
[torch.ByteTensor of size 7]
```

Or

```
z1 = torch.add(x,y)
z1[z1:gt(1)] = 1 -- removes double counting

th> z1
 1
 1
 0
 1
 0
 1
 1
[torch.ByteTensor of size 7]
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing the same thing!